# what is '#access' => $admin in this code

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

im want to 3 radio buttons and user select a one save it in data base and i use following code but it gives error like this

> Notice: Undefined variable: admin in ounces_to_ml_form() (line 44 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7\sites\all\modules\ounces_to_ml\ounces_to_ml.module).
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: admin in ounces_to_ml_form() (line 54 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7\sites\all\modules\ounces_to_ml\ounces_to_ml.module).
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: admin in ounces_to_ml_form() (line 64 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7\sites\all\modules\ounces_to_ml\ounces_to_ml.module).

```
$active = array(0 => t('Closed'), 1 => t('Active'));
  

$form['settings']['active'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radio',
    '#title' => t('every time'),
    '#default_value' => isset($node->active) ? $node->active : 1,
    '#options' => $active,
    '#description' => t('Instantly: Emailed every time a donor submits a donation'),
    '#access' => $admin,
  );
//////////////////////
//////radio 02 /////////
$form['settings']['active1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radio',
    '#title' => t('once a day'),
    '#default_value' => isset($node->active) ? $node->active : 1,
    '#options' => $active,
    '#description' => t(' Email once a day'),
    '#access' => $admin,
  );
//////////////////////
//////radio 03 /////////
$form['settings']['active2'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radio',
    '#title' => t('at given time'),
    '#default_value' => isset($node->active) ? $node->active : 1,
    '#options' => $active,
    '#description' => t('Email a day'),
    '#access' => $admin,
  );
//////////////////////

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('save'),
  );
 
  
return $form;
```

i want to know what is the error and what is mean by  '#access' => $admin code line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`#access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#access) property in Form API is to set whether the element should be visible to the user or not. 
If its value is `TRUE`, the element will not be displayed (not hidden element - `#required` will not be enforced). 
From Form API doc:

> Whether the element is accessible or not; when FALSE, the element is
>   not rendered and the user submitted value is not taken into
>   consideration.

`$admin` should be a variable you have forgotten to add/take from where you took the code.

Here is my suggestion to populate `$admin` variable. At top of the form function, populate `$admin`:

```
$admin = user_access('administer site configuration');
```

user_access function returns `(bool) TRUE` of the user has the given permission (or FALSE if the current user doesn't). `administer site configuration` is a general permission that will be usually given to administrators. 
You can use whatever permission as appropriate for this.